# swagger core 2.0 disable security for endpoint

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I am using Swagger Core 2.0 to generate openAPI 3.0 definition files and
I am having trouble to disable "security" for a particular endpoint. 
I have my securitySchemes and root security element defined:

```
{
  "openapi" : "3.0.1",
  "security" : [ {
    "JWT" : [ ]
  } ],
  "paths" : {   
    "/auth" : {
      "post" : {
        "summary" : "authenticate user",
        "operationId" : "authenticate",
        "requestBody" : {
          "content" : {
            "application/json" : {
              "schema" : {
                "$ref" : "#/components/schemas/AuthenticationRequest"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "responses" : {
          "200" : {
            "description" : "when user is successfully authenticated",
            "content" : {
              "application/json" : {
                "schema" : {
                  "$ref" : "#/components/schemas/AuthenticateUserOutput"
                }
              }
            }
          },       
          "401" : {
            "description" : "when email/password not valid or user is blocked/inactive"
          }       
        }
      }
    },
  },
  "components" : {
    "schemas" : {
      "AuthenticateUserOutput" : {
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
          "token" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "lastLoginAt" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "format" : "date-time"
          },        
          "lastProjectId" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      },
      ...,
      "AuthenticationRequest" : {
        "required" : [ "email", "password" ],
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
          "email" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "password" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "securitySchemes" : {
      "JWT" : {
        "type" : "http",
        "scheme" : "bearer",
        "bearerFormat" : "JWT"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

According to OPEN API 3 spec https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md#securityRequirementObject i shall be able to  override global "security requirement" for an individual operation. I would like to "disable" JWT security for a few operations and according to https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/3.0.1/versions/3.0.1.md#securityRequirementObject it can be done:

> To remove a top-level security declaration, an empty array can be used.

Unfortunately I am struggling to define "empty security array" on Operation level using annotations...
I tried to specify

```
security = {}
```

or

```
security = @SecurityRequirement(name ="")
```

but no security element within operation is generated at all....
Any idea ?

Below is my java code (i use for swagger dropwizard integration) that allows one to have SecurityScheme and root level security defined

```
 Info info = new Info()
            .title("someTitle")
            .description("some description")
            .version("1.0")

    SecurityScheme jwtSecurity = new SecurityScheme()
            .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
            .name("Authorization")
            .in(SecurityScheme.In.HEADER)
            .scheme("bearer")
            .bearerFormat("JWT");

    String securitySchemaName = "JWT";
    OpenAPI oas = new OpenAPI()
            .info(info)
            .components(new Components().addSecuritySchemes(securitySchemaName, jwtSecurity))
            .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList(securitySchemaName));

    SwaggerConfiguration oasConfig = new SwaggerConfiguration()
            .openAPI(oas)
            .prettyPrint(true)
            .resourcePackages(Stream.of("my.resources.package")
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    environment.jersey().register(new OpenApiResource()
            .openApiConfiguration(oasConfig));
```

Then on a few dedicated endpoints i would like to disable security, so i am trying with:

```
    @POST
@Operation(
        summary = "authenticate user",
        responses = {
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "when user is successfully authenticated",
                        content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = AuthenticateUserOutput.class))),                   
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "when email/password not valid or user is blocked/inactive"),
        }
        ,security = what to put here ?
)
```

Comment: Could you post your Java code with annotations?

Comment: I just edited a post to add global configuration and endpoint specific configuration

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? It's currently causing me a headache

Answer (score 4):

if you want to do it in yml swagger hub style you can put

```
security: []
```

in that endpoint after request body, So swagger considers it as no auth for that particular path or endpoint.

Comment: Nice, this is the correct way of disabling authentication in a single endpoint when you have an OpenAPI specs document that declares a security configuration globally.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Building REST API with **Spring Boot** and **Spring Doc**), I've configured all of endpoints secure, however there are some endpoints that needs to be public. In order to make particular endpoint public, I've added following annotation on top of the method inside Controller.

```java
@SecurityRequirements(value = {})
```

Answer (score -1):

According to a comment over on the [OpenAPI-Specifiction GitHub](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/14#issuecomment-297457320) project. It should be possible.

Did you try this?

```
security: [
  {}
]
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, on a Java SpringBoot webapp (dependency org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.5.2). As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59430454/8745150), I solved it adding an empty `@SecurityRequirements` annotation on the operation. For example:

```java
@POST
@SecurityRequirements
@Operation(
    summary = "authenticate user",
    responses = {
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "when user is successfully authenticated",
                 content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = AuthenticateUserOutput.class))),                   
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "when email/password not valid or user is blocked/inactive"),
    } )
)
```