# springdoc-openapi apply default global SecurityScheme possible?

Tags: java, spring, swagger, openapi, springdoc

I have the following [`SecurityScheme`](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v2.1.1/apidocs/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/security/SecurityScheme.html) definition using springdoc-openapi for java SpringBoot RESTful app:

```
    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .components(new Components().addSecuritySchemes("bearer-jwt",
                 new SecurityScheme().type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP).scheme("bearer").bearerFormat("JWT")
                .in(SecurityScheme.In.HEADER).name("Authorization")))
                .info(new Info().title("App API").version("snapshot"));
    }
```

Is it possible to apply it globally to all paths, without having to go and add [`@SecurityRequirement`](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v2.1.1/apidocs/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/security/SecurityRequirement.html) annotations to [`@Operation`](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v2.1.1/apidocs/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/Operation.html) annotation everywhere in the code?

If it is, how to add exclusions to unsecured paths?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, you can do it in the same place calling `addSecurityItem`:

```
  @Bean
  public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
    return new OpenAPI()
            .components(new Components().addSecuritySchemes("bearer-jwt",
                new SecurityScheme().type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP).scheme("bearer").bearerFormat("JWT")
                    .in(SecurityScheme.In.HEADER).name("Authorization")))
            .info(new Info().title("App API").version("snapshot"))
            .addSecurityItem(
                    new SecurityRequirement().addList("bearer-jwt", Arrays.asList("read", "write")));
  }
```

Global security schema can be overridden by a different one with the `@SecurityRequirements` annotation. Including removing security schemas for an operation. For example, we can remove security for registration path.

```
@SecurityRequirements
@PostMapping("/registration")
public ResponseEntity post(@RequestBody @Valid Registration: registration) {
    return registrationService.register(registration);
}
```

While still keeping security schemas for other APIs.

**Old answer (Dec 20 '19):**

Global security schema can be overridden by a different one with the `@SecurityRequirements` annotation. but it cannot be removed for unsecured  paths. It is acctualy missing fueature in the **springdoc-openapi**, OpenAPI standard allows it. See [disable global security for particular operation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/2844)

There is a workaround though. The **springdoc-openapi** has a concept of an OpenApiCustomiser which can be used to intercept generated schema. Inside the customizer, an operation can be modified programmatically. To remove any inherited security, the field `security` needs to be set to an empty array. The logic may be based on any arbitrary rules e.g operation name. I used tags.

The customizer:

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.PathItem;
import org.springdoc.api.OpenApiCustomiser;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

@Component
public class SecurityOverrideCustomizer implements OpenApiCustomiser {

    public static final String UNSECURED = "security.open";

    private static final List<Function<PathItem, Operation>> OPERATION_GETTERS = Arrays.asList(
            PathItem::getGet, PathItem::getPost, PathItem::getDelete, PathItem::getHead,
            PathItem::getOptions, PathItem::getPatch, PathItem::getPut);

    @Override
    public void customise(OpenAPI openApi) {
        openApi.getPaths().forEach((path, item) -> getOperations(item).forEach(operation -> {
            List<String> tags = operation.getTags();
            if (tags != null && tags.contains(UNSECURED)) {
                operation.setSecurity(Collections.emptyList());
                operation.setTags(filterTags(tags));
            }
        }));
    }

    private static Stream<Operation> getOperations(PathItem pathItem) {
        return OPERATION_GETTERS.stream()
                .map(getter -> getter.apply(pathItem))
                .filter(Objects::nonNull);
    }

    private static List<String> filterTags(List<String> tags) {
        return tags.stream()
                .filter(t -> !t.equals(UNSECURED))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Now we can add `@Tag(name = SecurityOverrideCustomizer.UNSECURED)` to unsecured methods:

```
    @Tag(name = SecurityOverrideCustomizer.UNSECURED)
    @GetMapping("/open")
    @ResponseBody
    public String open() {
        return "It works!";
    }
```

Please bear in mind that it is just a workaround. Hopefully, the issue will be resolved in the next **springdoc-openapi** versions (at the time of writing it the current version is 1.2.18).

For a working example see [springdoc-security-override-fix](https://github.com/mafor/springdoc-security-override-fix)

Comment: Could you please guide me here: https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/363 ?

Comment: @PAA It seems to be solved, isn't it? If not, please post the question on SA, I'll be glad to help.

Comment: @Mafor is the same possible using annotations?

Answer (score 7):

Tested with v1.2.29 of springdoc-openapi: Its possible to disable security for particular Endpoint using: @SecurityRequirements

```
@GetMapping("/open")
@ResponseBody
@SecurityRequirements
public String open() {
    return "It works!";
}
```

For older versions, for example tested with v1.2.28 using OperationCustomizer:

```
public static final String UNSECURED = "security.open";

@Bean
public OperationCustomizer customize() {
    return (Operation operation, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) -> {
        List<String> tags = operation.getTags();
        if (tags != null && tags.contains(UNSECURED)) {
            operation.setSecurity(Collections.emptyList());
            operation.setTags(tags.stream()
                    .filter(t -> !t.equals(UNSECURED))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }
        return operation;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Documentation of springdoc, for new versions you can do this

Add the @SecurityRequirement for the protected route like

```java
 @PostMapping(value = "/example")
 @SecurityRequirement(name = "bearer-key")
 public ResponseEntity<Object> exampleHandler() {
    /// logic here
 }
```

and then in your Security config class add

```java
@Bean
 public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
   return new OpenAPI()
          .components(new Components()
          .addSecuritySchemes("bearer-key",
          new SecurityScheme().type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP).scheme("bearer").bearerFormat("JWT")));
}
```

Here is the link to the [docs](https://springdoc.org/#how-do-i-add-authorization-header-in-requests)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation for the opaque token (with Spring Boot 3):

```
@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {

        // https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/3.0.1/versions/3.0.1.md#securitySchemeObject
        var securityScheme = new SecurityScheme()
                .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
                .name("bearer")
                .scheme("bearer")
                .bearerFormat("opaque")
                .in(SecurityScheme.In.HEADER)
                .name("Authorization");
        var securityComponent = new Components()
                .addSecuritySchemes("bearer", securityScheme);
        var securityItem = new SecurityRequirement()
                .addList("bearer");

        return new OpenAPI()
                .components(securityComponent)
                .addSecurityItem(securityItem);
                // ... other details as needed
    }
}
```

Note that if controller classes or methods are annotated with `@SecurityRequirement`, the name used in these requirements has to match name used in the scheme above, i.e.

```
@Operation(summary = "...", security = {@SecurityRequirement(name = "bearer")})
```