# Authorization button in Swagger and enter bearer token in Spring Boot 3.0.0 project

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, swagger

I want to achieve the authorization button in Swagger. For the older version, there were some configurations for Swagger, but I guess those configurations are not needed in the newer version. Added a picture that I want to achieve. I know what Basic auth but my requirement is a header i.e authorization of the bearer and token. Thanks in advance for the help.

[image]

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59357205/springdoc-openapi-apply-default-global-securityscheme-possible

Comment: Check this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59357205/springdoc-openapi-apply-default-global-securityscheme-possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59357205/springdoc-openapi-apply-default-global-securityscheme-possible).

Answer (score 2):

Added

```
@SecurityScheme(
    name = "bearerAuth",
    scheme = "bearer",
    bearerFormat = "JWT", 
    type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP, 
    in = SecuritySchemeIn.HEADER
)
```

This configuration is in the main class.

Add `@SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth")`

It is in the Controller class, or you can add it at your endpoints, which works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a `@Configuration` class with OpenApi information.
There, you should configure your `OpenAPI()` instance with the following:

```
new OpenAPI().
//... whatever configuration you have
    .components(
        new Components().addSecuritySchemes(
            "api",
            new SecurityScheme()
                .scheme("bearer")
                .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
                .bearerFormat("jwt") //if it is your case
                .name("api") 
        )
    )
```

Sorry I'm translating it from Kotlin, but you got the Java idea :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but no configuration is needed for the new spring boot version. I got the Solution in one line.

Comment: @AnilSingh can you please share your solution?